# Are Autosys questions OT for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic, scope

Autosys questions make my head hurt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074868/remove-a-condition-in-autosys-job-jil-file

Is this programming related *at all?* [Are **any** of them programming related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autosys)

Comment: Happy traiiiiils to you.... until we meet again...

Comment: I'm not sure why this is still sitting here well over two years later, but I also just came across [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859710/different-timezone-in-autosys-detailed-report) [tag:autosys] question.  Don't *all* of these questions deserve to be migrated to superuser or serverfault?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is 2.5+ years old and still unanswered, I'm gonna go out on a limb and suggest that **yes**, these are programming questions. Some of them, at least.

Granted, this doesn't look like a *general-purpose* programming system - it's designed to handle a specific set of tasks and hence the code is more like makefiles or cron files than, say, C#. But in the sense that you're writing *some sort of code* to ensure that certain behaviors are implemented, it qualifies as programming.

Comment: Perhaps Autosys has a scripting aspect to it, but a great deal of these questions aren't related to that at all.  Perhaps someone that knows the tool should go through and figure out which questions deserve migration?

Comment: Migration? Have you looked around? There's  no indication they belong on another site, at least as far as tagged activity goes.